# Turn results of count distinct into something that can be aggregated

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, analytics, business-intelligence, distinct-values

I have a table like this:

```
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| category | sub_category | customer_id |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
|    A     |     AB2      |    A876     |
|    A     |     AB2      |    A876     |
|    A     |     AA1      |    A876     |
|    A     |     AA1      |    A876     |
|    A     |     AC3      |    A756     |
|    B     |     AB2      |    A876     |
|    B     |     AA1      |    A756     |
|    B     |     AB7      |    A908     |
|    C     |     AA1      |    A756     |
|    C     |     AB7      |    A908     |
|    C     |     AC3      |    A908     |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
```

And I want to count distinct customers so I can easily do something like:

```
SELECT category, sub_category, COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) as count_of_customers
  FROM tbl
  GROUP BY category, sub_category
```

And I get a report that gives  me distinct customers for each sub_category and category. But these numbers can no longer be aggregated as there needs to be de-duplication if I just need distinct customers by category only.

For e.g customer_id = 'A876' will be counted twice in category='A' (once in sub_category = 'AB2' and once in sub_category = 'AA1') if I just sum the count_of_customers from my query result.

So here is the question, I would like to make these query results "aggregatable". Looking at the problem, it looks like this just isn't possible but I am wondering if there some clever way of distributing these results across categories? so that in my reporting layer (like an excel pivot table), I can get a result that counts 'A876' once in category='A' but counts it twice when I also include sub_category in the fields. Basically converting the results into something summable.

I should mention that this is an overly simplified example. The solution will need to generalize across ***n*** different categories and sub_categories.

I am looking for an output that would easily allow me to get either of the following results in something similar to a pivot table (think tableau-like reporting tools):

```
+----------+--------------------+
| category | distinct_customers |
+----------+--------------------+
|    A     |         2          |
|    B     |         3          |
|    C     |         2          |
+----------+--------------------+


+--------------+--------------------+
| sub_category | distinct_customers |
+--------------+--------------------+
|     AA1      |         2          |
|     AB2      |         1          |
|     AB7      |         1          |
|     AC3      |         2          |
+--------------+--------------------+
```

My immediate thought is to assign weights to a customer_id depending on how many categories and sub_categories it occurs in but I don't know exactly how I'd go about doing this.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Tagged to redshift, although I am happy with a general solution that I edit for my use case, mostly want to know if this is a solvable problem.

Comment: What is the result that you are looking for?

Comment: it would be better if you post the expected results

Comment: Expected output(s) added.

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly what you want -- assigning weights.  But this still won't aggregate correctly.  Assuming there are no duplicates:

```
select category, sub_category,
       count(distinct customer_id),
       sum(1.0 / num_cs) as weighted_customers
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by customer_id) as num_cs
      from t
     ) t
group by category, sub_category;
```

This weights by both `category` and `sub_category`.  Obviously, you can adjust the `partition by` to weight by just one or the other.